# jclouds: how to supply own KeyStore when creating BlobStoreContext

Tags: java, https, ssl-certificate, jclouds

I have a private blob store (swift) with a self-signed certificate.

I want to use this store with jclouds. Now, the following works:

```
Properties overrides = new Properties();
overrides.setProperty(Constants.PROPERTY_ENDPOINT, "https://example.com:8080/auth");
overrides.setProperty(Constants.PROPERTY_TRUST_ALL_CERTS, "true");
overrides.setProperty(Constants.PROPERTY_RELAX_HOSTNAME, "true");

BlobStoreContext context = new BlobStoreContextFactory().createContext("swift", 
    userCredentials.getIdent(), userCredentials.getSecret(), 
    ImmutableSet.<Module> of(), overrides);
```

However, since I have the certificate, is there a way to make this more secure and tell jclouds to use that particular certificate rather than trust any?

I do know how to get the certificate loaded into a `Certificate` object and I also know how to create a `KeyStore` object with the certificate.

My question is: How do I get jclouds to use my `Certificate` or `KeyStore` for certificate validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, jclouds doesn't provide this hook, so you'd have to modify the JRE keystore.  feel free to add a feature request for this here: http://code.google.com/p/jclouds/issues/entry

Answer (score 0):

As Adrian pointed out to me on jclouds-user maillist, it is possible now, by adding a module like this:

```
.modules(ImmutableSet.of(new AbstractModule(){
 @Override public void configure() {
  bind(new TypeLiteral<Supplier<SSLContext>>(){}).toInstance(new
   Supplier<SSLContext>() {
    @Override public SSLContext get() {
     return whatYouManage; // note this is called per-request so
                           //can be expensive.
     }
  }
 }
}))
```